# Handling two forms in the same view

Tags: python, django

I have the following stripped function.

```
def jobs(request):
    pms = PM.objects.all()
    a = Job.objects.all().filter(enddate__gte=datetime.date.today()).order_by('enddate')
    ljform = LaunchJobForm(request.POST or None)
    form = LimitedJobForm(request.POST or None, prefix='add')
    if request.method=='POST' and 'addjobbtn' in request.POST:
      if form.is_valid():
       ...do stuff...
    elif request.method=='POST' and 'launchjobbtn' in request.POST:
      print('test')
      ... do other stuff...
```

My ljform is

```
<form method='POST' action = '' class='launchjob'>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ ljform }}
    <td><button class = 'btn btn-primary' name='launchjobbtn' type='submit'>Launch Job</button></td>
    <td><input id='emailcheck' type="checkbox">Modify Email</input></td>
</form>
```

My addjob form is:

```
<div class='jobfrm{% if form.errors %} has_errors{% endif %}'>
    <span class='closex' >&#10006;</span>
    <form method='POST' action = '' class='addjob'>{% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <input class = 'btn btn-default' name='addjobbtn' type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'/>
    </form> 
</div>
```

My problem is that when I click the launch job button form validation errors are triggered on the jobfrm. It doesn't actually take that if path. It does take the elif path and prints 'test'. But I cannot figure out why it's triggering the other form.

Comment: I'd personally handle it much more clearly. Instead of 1 view I'd use 2 separate views (functions or class-based one) and 2 template tags. Then add to form attribute "action="/url_of_that_view/" which will be requested on submit action. In my opinion this approach is well arranged unlike 1 big chaotic view.

Comment: I've tried this solution type before but my problem with it is (and maybe I did it wrong) that I don't want to forward the user to another page just to submit the form.

Comment: Yes, it's easy. Just after submiting you can redirect back to the url from the user came or redirect to homepage or use AJAX for returning errors and saving the form in background without loading or redirecting pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only want to pass `request.POST` as an argument to your form if that is the form that has been submitted. This means you have to do something like this:

```
def jobs(request):

    pms = PM.objects.all()
    a = Job.objects.all().filter(enddate__gte=datetime.date.today()).order_by('enddate')

    ljform = LaunchJobForm()
    form = LimitedJobForm()

    if request.method=='POST' and 'addjobbtn' in request.POST:
        form = LimitedJobForm(request.POST)          
        if form.is_valid():
         ...do stuff...

    elif request.method=='POST' and 'launchjobbtn' in request.POST:
        ljform = LaunchJobForm(request.POST)
        print('test')
        ... do other stuff...
```

Comment: In doing this though both forms don't get passed into context so they don't get rendered and I get `Exception Value: 
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You will have to include more information from the `views.py`/`forms.py` file. In my answer above, `form` and `ljform` will be passed to the context as normal.....

Comment: You just need suitable `else` statements that instantiate the forms without the POST, surely.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ie instead of the way I instantiate `ljform` and `form` before the `if` statements?

Comment: Sorry my message was to the OP, to solve their exception.

Comment: Thanks, this goes to show how bad my grasp of django still is.. what a simple solution that I wouldn't have thought worked but makes perfect sense.